# Get first specific elements from a defined total of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice, element, children

I have

```
<table id="ok">
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="blue">Blue</div></tr>
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="blue">Blue</div></tr>
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="red">Red</div></tr>
<tr><div class="blue">Blue</div></tr>
<tr><div class="blue">Blue</div></tr>
.......
List goes on and on
</table>
```

I want to get first 10 elements of table "ok" and from those 10, i want to get all elements with class "red"
In this case, I would get only 6 elements.

I have went only this far

```
var total = $("#ok tr"); var red = total.slice(1, 11);
```

Comment: `$("#ok").find('.red')` return all elements with class red.

Comment: OMG.. Invalid html. I didn't notice that and answered it.. Sighhh..

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<div>` elements don't belong as the direct child of a `<tr>`

Comment: wow me either lol - meh i will leave my answer - what you were doing was right in terms of jquery usage - just the HTML - I can tell its Sunday missing that as well lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with one selector, using jQuery's [`:lt` extension](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and a descendant selector:

```
var redsWithinFirst10Rows = $("#ok tr:lt(10) .red");
```

That says: "Within the element with the `id` `ok`, select the rows with zero-based indexes less than 10 (so, 0-9) and select the descendants of those rows with the class `.red`." (Yes, jQuery extension selectors use 0-based indexes rather than the usual 1-based ones in CSS.)

**Live Example:**

```js
var redsWithinFirst10Rows = $("#ok tr:lt(10) .red");
redsWithinFirst10Rows.css("color", "red");
```

```html
<table id="ok">
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="red">Red</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="blue">Blue</div></td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you have to fix your markup, `div` isn't valid as a direct child of `tr`.

Comment: I think he wants the elements that are the `.red` subset of the first 10, so it should be a `.filter()` operation to get the `.red`.

Comment: @squint: I don't follow you.

Comment: It worked they way it couldnt work better. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing in your approach is `find()`

```
var red = total.slice(0, 10).find('.red');
```

Slice the rows, then *find* the red class within those rows

Comment: This is the way to do this - slice is FAR more efficient than :lt as :lt will still loop through the whole set.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Huh? That's what `total` is: The whole set. I doubt this is more efficient in that way. It *may* be more efficient because the initial selection can be handed off to the browser, which isn't the case with jQuery extensions. Though it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: I got curious how much `:lt` cost vs. the extra `find`, and am slightly surprised to find `:lt` was *faster* than `slice`+`find` with 10,000 rows: https://jsfiddle.net/yvorsod3/ Again, not that it matters, we're talking 0.5-2ms.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder speaks well to all the selector optimizations jQ team has done

Comment: @charlietfl: It does indeed -- and the speed of modern JavaScript engines.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am a bit shocked also because the internal `each` for `find()` only has 10 elements to go through

Comment: @charlietfl: Yeah. I don't think it's the `find`. I suppose we could analyze further, but I suspect it's building the initial `$("#ok tr")` when dealing with 10k elements. It occurs to me I should have tested the reasonable case (a couple of dozen), maybe it goes the other way. I went with 10k primarily to make `:lt` work its hardest, but maybe I inadvertently gave it an advantage.

Comment: @charlietfl: Yup: https://jsfiddle.net/yvorsod3/1/ With just 20 elements, `slice`+`find` wins. On Chrome, 0.1ms vs. 0.31ms; On Firefox, 0.35ms vs. 0.56ms. (Caveat again: not that it matters. :-) )

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".red").slice(0,10);
```

read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)
http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: still not what OP is asking for ... all red but only in first 10 rows is what i iterpret

Comment: YEs, I tried that, but that instead would get first 10 elements, I want to get only first x elements with class "red" within first 10 table elements. So, in my case it would only get 6 red elements.

Comment: see @charlietfl answer - that is what you want and is the most efficient method - if you want legibility use T.J's answer but beware of speed if you have hundreds or thousands or rows.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: See my [comment on your other statement about `:lt` being slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249135/get-first-specific-elements-from-a-defined-total-of-elements/36249197#comment60128462_36249271). Somewhat to my surprise, it's faster (in one synthetic test with 10k rows).